is it idiomatic / correct to have a project-wide prelude.ts module, and what is wrong with the loading order?
I have the following module: dummy.ts
console.log("*** top level");

export function dummy() {
    console.log("*** dummy");
}

in addition I have a prelude.ts module:
export * as d from "./dummy";

then, somewhere else, I import my prelude.ts, and call the dummy() function.
import { d } from "./prelude";

d.dummy();

and what I see in the console surprises me:
*** dummy
*** top level

It seems that the log statement I have on the top-level is executed AFTER the dummy() function got called (and loaded, etc). I'm not very experienced with {Type,Java}Script languages, but this looks really weird to me.
Actually the way I noticed it - is that I had some import in dummy.ts. And when I used within dummy() function - it was undefined.
When I skip the prelude.ts module, and import dummy.ts directly - everything returns to normal and ordering get's correct.
In other languages I'm using, it's idiomatic to create project specific prelude module, to quickly import various frequently required things. Is there something wrong with such approach in TypeScript?
The compiler is totally fine with such setup, and no errors/warnings are produced.
Update
I guess, this is the compiler settings:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
}


Here's your example code, base64-encoded as a single data URL: await import("data:text/javascript;base64,aW1wb3J0IHsgZCB9IGZyb20gImRhdGE6dGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0O2Jhc2U2NCxaWGh3YjNKMElDb2dZWE1nWkNCbWNtOXRJQ0prWVhSaE9uUmxlSFF2YW1GMllYTmpjbWx3ZER0aVlYTmxOalFzV1RJNWRXTXlPWE5hVXpWellqSmpiMGxwYjNGTGFVSXdZak5CWjJKSFZqSmFWM2RwUzFSelMwTnRWalJqUnpsNVpFTkNiV1JYTldwa1IyeDJZbWxDYTJSWE1YUmxVMmR3U1VoelMwTlhUblppYms1MllrZFZkV0pIT1c1TFEwbHhTMmx2WjFwSVZuUmlXR3RwUzFSelMyWlJQVDBpT3c9PSI7CgpkLmR1bW15KCk7")

^ You can copy & paste it into your browser's JS console and run it to see that the output is what you expect rather than what you described observing. The filenames you showed end in .ts and are (presumably) being compiled by the TypeScript compiler (tsc), but you don't show what compilation settings are being used or how you are executing the compiled JavaScript code.

^ Can you [edit] the question to include that information and also the compiled JavaScript that is actually being executed by the runtime?

in your variant the order is correct. But I still don't get how the compiler having something, seemingly valid produces something that is not valid. There are two options, either I'm doing something wrong, or the compiler is not correct. I would assume that that it's me (not very experienced TS developer). So the question is - what exactly is wrong with my code?

^ @aav Your question still does not contain enough information to reproduce your claim. Please review how to provide a [mre] and [edit] the question to update it accordingly.

yes. i'm trying to make the minimal example.
but still, is there anything wrong, in the input language I have? after 30 years of programming I'm used to that valid input + valid compiler produce valid code (put libraries aside). how different compiler settings may lead to fundamentally different behavior?  (unless this is the case for UB, that's actually what I try find out).

@jsejcksn I narrowed down the problem, to the situation, when my prelude.ts is included into a dependency cycle.
When I break this cycle, the execution order get's fixed. So the root cause is now clear.
But I'm still confused - if circular dependencies between modules are not allowed - why compiler is silent about them. If they are ok - why do they have impact on execution logic?

^ @aav I’m going to disengage here. If your question is edited to include the required information (refer to my previous comments), then future engagement might be possible. Good luck!

@jsejcksn no problem. thank you, anyways. the specific problem is solved, and the root reason behind it is also more or less clear. The only missing thing is a global view on guarantees and behavior of the while tool chain. I'm still very confused on formal definition of what is valid, what to expect, etc. Specific solutions for specific problems are usually trivial.
For me it all looks very fragile and unreliable. But perhaps it's all due to my minimal experience with the topic.

^ @aav TypeScript has no specification — only an implementation. See e.g. microsoft/TypeScript#15711

I'm not very experienced with {Type,Java}Script languages Java and JavaScript have absolutely nothing in common, learning one will not help you learn the other.
